# systemctl: Write console message to particular file

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-16.04

I have a service configured with systemctl. This is the config file:

```
[Unit]
Description=eureka-server
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=bhushanp
#User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/bhushanp/apps/eureka_server.jar > /var/log/es.log 2>>&1
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But its not writing logs to /var/log/es.log file.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecStart` is not managed by a shell, so if you want that, prefix it with `/bin/sh -c` and quote your arguments. I would recommend you rather let stdout be connected to the journal and look at log output using `journalctl -u foo.service` than grabbing it out of a file on disk.

If you want to follow the log in a similar fashion to `tail -f`, you can use `journalctl -f -u foo.service`.

Comment: Hi @Tollef, how can I see those logs in a `tail -f` kind of manner ?

Comment: You can use the -f flag to journalctl, so `journalctl -f -u foo.service`